# Menu nav close to when click menu outer div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried menu navigation view closing and opening using humburger icon, it is working fine. I try to menu outer div click, menu closing but again I clicked humburger menu it is not opening(Working), Please guide, how to solve this problem, sorry for poor english. Thanks advance.

```js
// Humburger menu working fine
function menushow() {
  if (document.getElementById("r_menu").className == "h_menu") {
    document.getElementById("r_menu").className = "s_menu";
    document.getElementById("menu_grp").className = "menu_grpa";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("r_menu").className = "h_menu";
    document.getElementById("menu_grp").className = "menu_grp";
  }
}

// menu outer click
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  var container = document.getElementById('r_menu1');
  if (!container.contains(e.target)) {
    document.getElementById("r_menu").className = "h_menu";
  }
}.bind(this));
```

```css
.w_100 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.humb {
  background: cyan;
  width: 80px;
  height: 25px;
}

.h_menu {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.s_menu {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  visibility: visible;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  z-index: 555;
}

ul.r_menu li {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu" class="w_100">
  <p onclick="menushow()" class="humb">Menu Click</p>
  <div id="r_menu" class="h_menu">
    <ul id="r_menu1" class="r_menu">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

In without menu outer click function, menu opening and closing working fine, I need to with outer click function and menu click opening and closing functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Please be clear what you want? The List is opening on clicking the "Menu Click" and closing fine when clicked anywhere else within "w_100" div.

Comment: The List is opening on clicking the "Menu Click" and closing fine when clicked anywhere else within "w_100" div.
Again we need to click "Menu click" button, list will be open and close. 
this is we want. Plz suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Stop using onclick() it is a bad practice.

Here i update your code and many styles. It is working with addEventListener

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anplusdre/bmLjkfwk/4/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu" class="w_100"><p id="buttonZ" class="humb">Menu Click</p>
                <div id="h_menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li>1</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>3</li>
                        <li>4</li>
                        <li>5</li>

                    </ul>
                </div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.w_100{
width:400px;
height:300px;
border:1px solid red;
}
.humb{
background:cyan;
width:80px;
line-height:25px;
padding: 0 10px;
}


#h_menu{
 width: 100px;
 height: 200px;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}

ul {
  list-style:none;
}

ul.r_menu li{
  border:1px solid red;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}
```

**Js**

```
document.getElementById("buttonZ").addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("h_menu");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @andre, actually, my requirement is  the same function with anywhere clicking automatically closed if opened menu list.